# Calculate group mean, sum, or other summary stats. and assign column to original data

Tags: r, mean, summary, dplyr, r-faq

I want to calculate `mean` (or any other summary statistics of length one, e.g. `min`, `max`, `length`, `sum`) of a numeric variable ("value") within each level of a grouping variable ("group").

The summary statistic should be assigned to a new variable which has the *same length* as the *original data*. That is, each row of the original data should have a value corresponding to the current group value - the data set should *not* be collapsed to one row per group. For example, consider group `mean`:

Before

```
id  group  value
1   a      10
2   a      20
3   b      100
4   b      200
```

After

```
id  group  value  grp.mean.values
1   a      10     15
2   a      20     15
3   b      100    150
4   b      200    150
```

Answer (score 35):

You may do this in `dplyr` using `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(grp.mean.values = mean(value))
```

...or use `data.table` to assign the new column by reference (`:=`):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , grp.mean.values := mean(value), by = group]
```

Answer (score 32):

Have a look at the `ave` function. Something like

```
df$grp.mean.values <- ave(df$value, df$group)
```

---

If you want to use `ave` to calculate something else per group, you need to specify `FUN = your-desired-function`, e.g. `FUN = min`:

```
df$grp.min <- ave(df$value, df$group, FUN = min)
```

Answer (score 7):

One option is to use `plyr`. `ddply` expects a `data.frame` (the first d) and returns a `data.frame` (the second d). Other XXply functions work in a similar way; i.e. `ldply` expects a `list` and returns a `data.frame`, `dlply` does the opposite...and so on and so forth. The second argument is the grouping variable(s). The third argument is the function we want to compute for each group.

```
require(plyr)
ddply(dat, "group", transform, grp.mean.values = mean(value))

  id group value grp.mean.values
1  1     a    10              15
2  2     a    20              15
3  3     b   100             150
4  4     b   200             150
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option using base functions `aggregate` and `merge`:

```
merge(x, aggregate(value ~ group, data = x, mean), 
     by = "group", suffixes = c("", "mean"))

  group id value.x value.y
1     a  1      10      15
2     a  2      20      15
3     b  3     100     150
4     b  4     200     150
```

You can get "better" column names with `suffixes`:

```
merge(x, aggregate(value ~ group, data = x, mean), 
     by = "group", suffixes = c("", ".mean"))


  group id value value.mean
1     a  1    10         15
2     a  2    20         15
3     b  3   100        150
4     b  4   200        150
```