# Grouping in R by Cells

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to group data in R by Education-Experience-Year cells. My search led me to the `dplyr` package, and I can use code like this

```
by_EdExpT <- df1 %>% group_by(ED, EXP, YEAR)
```

to group the data. But I'm not really sure how to perform operations on it. Is dplyr the best package to use for this, and how do I perform operations like means or regressions?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean by perform operations. You can use the `summarise()` function from `dplyr` to compute means by group, for example. It'll work for anything that produces one output per group.

```
summarise(by_EdExpT, mean)
```

If you want some overview of `dplyr` functionalities you can use the [cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) to check it out.

`mutate()` can include summary statistics to your original data, as an example:

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(avg = mean(Sepal.Length))
```

will add the `avg` column, that represents the average `Sepal.Length` for the `Species` corresponding the observation in each row.

Comment: This cheatsheet is very helpful, thank you. So, if I do:
    `df1 %>% group_by(ED, EXP, YEAR) %>% summarize(AvgW = 
    mean(INCWAGE))`, I get a table with the average wage by group, but what I really want is that to be added to my dataframe as a variable. The mutate command doesn't seem to do that, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you add a minimal reproducible example to your question? You can use the function `dput()` to include (a piece of) your data set.

Comment: Also, this question might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053620/calculate-group-mean-or-other-summary-stats-and-assign-to-original-data

Comment: I followed your edit to the main answer and it worked. Thanks so much there. One last thing, I've been trying `df1 %>%
  ungroup()` to undo the grouping and it seems to be failing, what other arguments do I need to include? I copied the documentation.