# What is the difference between ave() function and mean() function in R?

Tags: r

What is the difference between `ave()` and `mean()` function in `R`?

For example I am trying to find out the  average of a particular column of a dataframe in R?

I came across these two functions:

```
mean(dataset$age, na.rm= TRUE)
ave(dataset$age, FUN=function(x)mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The first function clearly gave me the mean as a single value. Whereas  the second function also gave me the mean but had as many elements as there were non-missing values in the rows of the dataframe. Why is it so? And what is the use of a function like `ave()` when mean neatly gives the ave?

Comment: `ave` by default does a `mean` by group and is used to create a new column as it returns an output with the same `length` as input and the order remains the same

Comment: @akrun - I didn't understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: `ave(1:10, rep(1:2, each = 5))` returns the mean of first 5 and next 5 with overlal length equal to 10 while `mean(1:10)` returns a single value with the whole mean of 1:10.  Regaring the order `ave(1:5 c(3, 4, 1, 3, 4))`. the mean values for each corressponding group will be returned in the same order as `c(3, 4, 1, 3, 4)`

Answer (score 16):

Elaborating on @akrun's comments -

Suppose `x <- 1:10`.

**1)** `mean` always ***returns vector of length 1***.

```
mean(x)
[1] 5.5
```

**2)** `ave` always ***returns a vector of same length as input vector***

```
ave(x)
[1] 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5
```

The cool thing about `ave` is that you can also divide `x` into groups and apply any function `FUN` to get an output, again, of same length as `x` -

Let's divide `x` in two groups of 3 and 7 elements each i.e. rep(1:2, each = 5)

```
(grouping <- rep(1:2, c(3,7)))
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

# Now calculating mean for each group -    
ave(x, grouping, FUN = mean)
[1] 2 2 2 7 7 7 7 7 7 7

# calculating sum for each group
ave(x, grouping, FUN = sum)
[1]  6  6  6 49 49 49 49 49 49 49

# any custom function can be applied to ave, not just mean
ave(x, grouping, FUN = function(a) sum(a^2))
[1]  14  14  14 371 371 371 371 371 371 371
```

Above results are similar to what you'd get from a `tapply` with the difference being that output is of the same length as x.

```
tapply(x, grouping, mean)
1 2 
2 7 

tapply(x, grouping, sum)
1  2 
6 49 

tapply(x, grouping, function(a) sum(a^2))
1   2 
14 371
```

Finally, you can define your own function and pass it to `FUN` argument of `ave` so you are not restricted to just calculating the `mean`.

The `output length = input length` property makes `ave` **very useful for adding columns to tabular data**. Example- [Calculate group mean (or other summary stats) and assign to original data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053620/calculate-group-mean-or-other-summary-stats-and-assign-to-original-data)