# How do I find median and mean of certain values in a column?

Tags: r

I have a large csv file, and I am trying to find the median and the mean values of certain values in a column.
One of my columns is titled 'Race' and another is called 'debt_to_income_ratio'.  Within the Race column, the four options are 'White', 'Black', 'Hispanic', and 'Other'.  The 'debt_to_income_ratio' column has a number in it indicating the debt to income ratio of whatever the race is in the 'Race' column.  I am trying to get a median and mean debt to income ratio for each race (white, black, hispanic, and other).

The code I am currently using is:

```
df['race average'] = df.groupby('Race')['debt_to_income_ratio'].transform('mean') %>%
df['race median'] = df.groupby('Race')['debt_to_income_ratio'].transform('median')
```

I'm not really sure what I should be doing, so thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is python or R ? Seems like a chimera... Can you clarify which programming language is this intended for and also can you share df by doing dput(head(df)) and pasting the output?

Comment: If this is a question about computing summary statistics by group of one variable, then it is a frequent duplicate. See [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847054/how-to-get-summary-statistics-by-group), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053620/calculate-group-mean-or-other-summary-stats-and-assign-to-original-data).

Comment: This is intended for R.

Comment: I use the code that the code suggested in 2, which was:   group_by(Race) %>%
  mutate(Race.mean.values = mean(debt_to_income_ratio)) .  A new column was created, but it all of the values were NA.

Comment: We don't have your data, and your only code is both in python (not R) and not completely correct python code (`%>%`?). Please spend a moment to improve this question to be a minimal reprex, where we have some representative data to play with. (Unambiguous data is best served with `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`, depending on several factors.) From there, if you have preferences for R "ecosystems" like base, `dplyr`, or `data.table`, please be explicit, otherwise answers might encourage packages with which you are not familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` to do this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Race) %>%
    mutate(Mean = mean(debt_to_income_ratio, na.rm = TRUE),
           Median = median(debt_to_income_ratio, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I tried this, and it came up with a column titled mean, but all of the values are NA.  Do you have any ideas what would be causing this?

Comment: @Lauren if there is any NA element, it returns NA, so you have use `na.rm = TRUE` by default, it is `na.rm = FALSE` in `mean` or `median`

Answer (score 0):

An option based on the base R `aggregate` function. Is this what you mean?

```
race_median = aggregate(debt_to_income_ratio ~ Race, data = df, FUN = function(x) quantile(x, 0.5, na.rm = T))
race_mean   = aggregate(debt_to_income_ratio ~ Race, data = df, FUN = "mean")
```

Comment: I tried that, but it says: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  object 'debt_to_income_ratio' not found

Comment: if you search `?aggregate` you'll see that the data argument is missing.  it should be `aggregate(formula, data, FUN)`