# R - inserting aggregate results into a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

To produce a cumulative plot using ggplot2 geom_stat(), I need a data.frame() that has the number of instances of various combinations of factors.  I know how to produce the numbers using aggregate(), e.g.

```
print(aggregate(cbind(count=prop_cost) ~ tax_cnt + data_set, data=out_data, FUN=function(x){NROW(x)}))
```

Gives me:

```
  tax_cnt data_set count
1       3    5taxa  1936
2       4    5taxa  3907
3       5    5taxa  7205
4       3  5taxaRS  1446
5       4  5taxaRS  2896
6       5  5taxaRS  6168
```

But how can I put these values back into the data.frame I am using to plot things?
I would like to set a new column, `$nt_cnt`, so that

```r
df[df$data_set=='5taxa' & df$tax_cnt==1,]$nt_cnt = 1936
```

and similarly for the other 5 sums.

This seems like it must be easy, but I need help.

Comment: Please make the question reproducible so others can easily run it by copying from the question and pasting into their R session. Include all `library` statements and  inputs (using `dput`). See top of [tag:r] tag page on how to ask a question.

Comment: If you're trying to summarise a dataframe by taking an average or sum, etc., use ```group_by() %>% summarise()``` from the dplyr package. If you're simply counting how many rows exist for different factors, use the count() function.

Comment: @MacgregorAubertin-Young OP says *"how can I put these values back into the data.frame I am using"*, so `mutate` not `summarise`.

Comment: @GregorThomas Yes, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Here's the FAQ [on calculating summary statistics and adding them back to the original data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6053620/903061).

Comment: In base R you could `merge(out_data, your_aggregate, all.x = TRUE)`. In `dplyr` you would `out_data %>% group_by(tax_cnt, data_set) %>% mutate(nt_cnt = n())`

Comment: Apparently 'ave()' is my friend in this case, as it makes it easy to aggregate() and merge().  It was certainly not something I would have thought of.