# How to find the median wage for X amount of quarters meeting some criteria

Tags: r

I am trying to find track the median quarterly wages for individuals based on the quarter they graduated, their demographic information, the program they graduated from, etc. For instance, if students graduated in 2012Q1 I would like to track their wages from 2012Q1 through 2020Q4 and be able to change the criteria quickly. Below is an example of the data I am dealing with.

```
People |grad.date|race|yrqtr|wage|program
PersonA|20121    |H   |20121|50  |Health
PersonA|20121    |H   |20122|50  |Health
PersonB|20122    |W   |20121|50  |Business
PersonB|20122    |W   |20122|75  |Business
PersonC|20131    |W   |20131|100 |Business
PersonC|20131    |W   |20132|50  |Business
PersonD|20121    |A   |20121|100 |Economics
PersonD|20121    |A   |20122|100 |Economics
```

Let's say I wanted to get the median wages for individuals that graduated in 2012Q1, the desired output would be:

```
People |grad.date|race|yrqtr  |wage|program  |Med.20121|Med.20122
PersonA|20121    |H   |20121  |50  |Health   |75       |75
PersonA|20121    |H   |20122  |50  |Health   |75       |75
PersonD|20121    |A   |20121  |100 |Economics|75       |75
PersonD|20121    |A   |20122  |100 |Economics|75       |75
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: I have edited with the desired output, however, I would like to add stipulations if I just wanted to look at Health, for example.

Comment: Have a look at the FAQ [Calculate group mean, sum, or other summary stats. and assign column to original data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6053620/903061). You can use `median` as your summary function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
After computing the medians you can filter the output below by `program == "Health"`, for instance.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

df1 %>%
  filter(grad.date == 20121) %>%
  group_by(People, grad.date) %>%
  mutate(wage = median(wage)) %>%
  left_join(
    df1 %>%
      group_by(grad.date) %>%
      mutate(Med = median(wage))
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = yrqtr, values_from = Med,
              names_glue = "{.value}.{yrqtr}")
#> Joining, by = c("People", "grad.date", "race", "yrqtr", "wage", "program")
#> # A tibble: 2 × 7
#> # Groups:   People, grad.date [2]
#>   People  grad.date race   wage program   Med.20121 Med.20122
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 PersonA     20121 H        50 Health           75        75
#> 2 PersonD     20121 A       100 Economics        75        75
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

```r
df1 <- "People |grad.date|race|yrqtr|wage|program
PersonA|20121    |H   |20121|50  |Health
PersonA|20121    |H   |20122|50  |Health
PersonB|20122    |W   |20121|50  |Business
PersonB|20122    |W   |20122|75  |Business
PersonC|20131    |W   |20131|100 |Business
PersonC|20131    |W   |20132|50  |Business
PersonD|20121    |A   |20121|100 |Economics
PersonD|20121    |A   |20122|100 |Economics"
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(df1), header = TRUE, sep = "|")
df1$race <- trimws(df1$race)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>